# How to wait while variable is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I have two "useEffect", the first just runs once, and the second one runs everytime a date is updated. The problem is that the second useEffect depends on a value that is setted on the first useEffect. Is there any simple way to make the second useEffect wait for that variable to be defined?

This is what I have:

```
useEffect(() => {
    database.collection('EmpleadosDev').get()
        .then(response => {
            const fetchedEmpleados = [];
            const emails = [];
            response.forEach(document => {
                const fetchedEmpleado = {
                    id: document.id,
                    ...document.data()
                };
                fetchedEmpleados.push(fetchedEmpleado);
                fetchedEmpleados.forEach(element => {
                    emails.push(element.Email)
                });
                if (!emails.includes(currentUser.email)) {
                    alert('Este usuario no tiene permisos de acceso. Serás redirigido al login');
                    firebase.auth().signOut();
                    throw BreakException;
                } else {
                    setEmpleadoSeleccionado(fetchedEmpleados[emails.indexOf(currentUser.email)]) **//This is what I need on the second useEffect**
                }
            });
            setEmpleados(fetchedEmpleados);
        })

}, [])
```

This is the second useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (empleadoSeleccionado !== undefined) //This works only when I update "startDate" {
        database.collection('NegociosDev').doc(empleadoSeleccionado.RefNegocio.path.split('/')[1]).collection('Negocios').doc(empleadoSeleccionado.RefNegocio.path.split('/')[3]).collection('citas').get()
            .then(response => {
                const fetchedCitas = [];
                const fetchedIDs = [];
                response.forEach(document => {
                    const fetchedCita = {
                        id: document.id,
                        ...document.data()
                    };
                    const fetchedID = document.id;

                    fetchedIDs.push(fetchedID);
                    if (fetchedCita.CheckIn.split(' ')[0] === startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]) {
                        fetchedCitas.push(fetchedCita);
                    }
                });
                setCitas(fetchedCitas);
                setIDs(fetchedIDs)

            })
    }
}, [startDate])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can use a second parameter on the useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //code
}, [par1, par2])
```

and it will fire everytime either one changes.